# jquery .get how to access different controller in mVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, get

i am making jquery get to call a controller JSON action.

$.get("/Account/IsEmailAvailable", ..

When i make the call the actual URL is prefixed with the current controller (Home/Account/IsEmailAvailable) so the URL is not found.. how can i call it directly without having to enter the full URL with domain??

Comment: The leading slash should indicate a URL from the root of the site. Have you checked the routing code and controller for typos?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('<%: Url.Action("IsEmailAvailable", "Account", ..., ...) %>', ..
```

Comment: That won't work. ActionLink is going to create an anchor tag.

Comment: Oops, you're right, wrong methood. See Tridus's response. (I'll edit this one to be accurate)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Razor:

$.get('@Url.Action("IsEmailAvailable", "Account", null, null)', ...

When you run that, Razor will create a URL that goes to the Account Controller's IsEmailAvailable action. It'll also continue to work if you change the URL to the app on the server, which is nice. :)